# User Data in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

is there any flag that determine if a user is active or not in orchard?
Because I tried to delete a user in orchard but the record is still exists in tables:
xxx_Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord
xxx_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord

So I'm guessing there's another table that stores this info?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are content types and Orchard creates content items for each user. When you create a new user Orchard adds records to xxx_Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord, xxx_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord, xxx_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord and xxx_Orchard_Roles_UserRolesPartRecord if you linked any roles to the user.

The xxx_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord table keeps track of the version number and whether or not a content item is published or not and which version of the published content item is the latest.

When you delete the user Orchard does not delete the records from the tables, but simply creates a new version record and sets Published and Latest columns to 0 for the new version and the old version. Because there is no published and latest version the content item does not show up on the list of users.

Comment: Thank You Stephan for your great explanation

Comment: There is also a good article about the DB structure: http://sebastienros.com/understanding-orchard-s-database